# Using <%= syntax for javascript in aspx pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using charts.js in one of the aspx page. Everything works except for one issue. Consider the code below,

```
window.myBar = new Chart(context).Bar(chData, {
    showScale: true,
    scaleLabel : "<%= Number(value).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',') + ' %'%>",
});
```

This works fine in a plain html page, but when used on the aspx page, the compiler tries to evaluate the code as aspx due to the `<%=` syntax that is used in aspx and it creates problems. Is there a way I can use this javascript code in aspx?

Comment: You mean that `<%=` should come in the actual HTML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by escaping the characters (symbolsw) and see if aspx still recognizes them (the expected is it should recognize them as plain text now).

```
"\<\%\= Number(value).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',') + ' %'\%\>"
```

or alternatively you can place your JavaScript code in a separate file

Comment: Escaping like this "<\%= works, I just figured that out after posting the question.

Comment: Hi, since lack of reputation to comment the other answer, for better/worse, its upto you but if its for readability i'd prefer using escape character and also it seems majority uses escape character for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

It feels like a workaround, but it does the job:

```
"<" + "%=
```

I do wonder though why one would want this.

Comment: It works. Also, I just figured out "<\%= works too. Would that be any better/worse?

Comment: I am not sure, haven't programmed WebForms for years now.

Answer (score 1):

replace "" in "<%= Number(value).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',') + ' %'%>" with '' and ' %' to " %" and  make it '<%= Number(value).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',') + " %"%>'. im new to this but this seemed to work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it a string:

```
<%= @"

window.myBar = new Chart(context).Bar(chData, {
        showScale: true,
        scaleLabel : ""<%= Number(value).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',') + ' %'%>"",
        });
" %>
```